# How can i access Views instance of Tables in ODBC using pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I want to access my database by using python script .

I can able to access all table by using

`SELECT * FROM poorvika1.payment;`

But i want to access the query by using VIEW Statement

`SELECT * FROM poorvika1.pymentview;`

This is my python script

```
import pyodbc

for py in pyodbc.drivers():
    print(py)
    
    
connection =pyodbc.connect(driver='SQL Server',server='localhost',database='test',uid='test',password='root')


cursor = connection.cursor()

for row in cursor.tables():
    print(row.table_name)
```

This Query is not working

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM poorvika1.pymentview')
```

[image]

I want to access view  query in pyodbc package

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly explain what you mean by   "not working". Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @GordThompson   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbNGT.png please check this images link

Comment: The screenshot suggests that you are working with a MySQL_8 server, yet your connection string specifies `driver='SQL Server'` which is the driver for *Microsoft* SQL Server, so that will never work. If you really are hitting a MySQL database, consider using [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) or [PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/pymysql/) instead of pyodbc.

Comment: For your understanding  i created  with mysql.  But original one sql only.  I connected sql several successfully.  After connecting i can able to access  store procedure and table also.but i want access  views query

Comment: Okay, so you need to show what happens when you try running a SELECT against a SQL Server view via pyodbc. If you get an error then [edit] your question to include the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM poorvika1..pymentview')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'GET_ITEM_MODEL_LIST'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM poorvika1..pymentview'